# How to simulate a React onMouseEnter/onMouseOver event with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, mouseevent, mouseover

More specifically, I'm trying to trigger the Facebook reactions layover that pops up when hovering over the Like button on the Facebook web version.
In the classic Facebook UI, this could be easily achieved by dispatching a mouseover Event:

```
likeButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', { view: window, bubbles: true }));
```

On the revamped Facebook UI, this does not work anymore, even after trying different alternative events.
I believe this is because the Like button is now a React component that triggers the popover in a onMouseEnter/onMouseOver listener.

Is there a specific/non-conventional way to simulate these events?

Comment: Facebook don't allow you to scrape them. Use the API. And if it is not possible in the API then it means you can't do it.

Comment: This is not about scraping. We work on an assistive software with which users interact with the Facebook website through an interface. There is a Keyboard shortcut (L) to trigger the overlay on the main Feed but this keyboard shortcut does not work on the Group and Timeline feed. Meaning this overlay is not accessible to users who do not  interact with a mouse/touch interface.